# Both commands give `Requirement already satisfied`

Tags: python, pip

I was trying to install a package called `configparser` on my local machine. Now, I have both `Python 2.7` as well as `Python 3.7.4` on my machine. Hence I wanted both versions of `configparser` to be installed.

I have set the default python version to be `Python 3.7.4`. So I used this command first:

1.`pip3 install configparser`:
which gave me requirement satisfied since I already had installed it.

Now, when I use:

2.`pip install configparser`:
it tells me that requirement is satisfied. But there is now package called configparser in Python 2.

What do I have to do to install the `Python2` version of `configparser` on my machine?

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I use Windows 10, develop in PyCharm.

Also, `pip -V` gives me:

`pip 19.1.1 from c:\users\ymodak\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the path of your envernnement variable to where python 2  is installed

or do this "path to pip in python2 directory"/pip install "Package"

if you want to configure pip to install packages on python 2 and pip3 to install packages on python3 you need to delete pip in python 3 directory and set both of paths in environnement variable python2 (path to pip in python2 directory)  and python3 (path to pip3 in python3 directory)

Answer (score 1):

It used to be that normally, 'python', 'pip' (and also 'ipython' if you use that) would be python 2, and to use python3, you have to explicitly say 'python3', 'pip3', 'ipython3'.

I have noticed recently (on Macs at least) that this is not necessarily still the case... on my Mac after installing 3.6.3, 'python' still points at a 2.7.15 install, but 'ipython' and 'pip' both point at the python3 version. This is just a general note that when mixing versions, you can end up with all kinds of mixed pointers to things - in my case, I have a system python at /usr/bin/python that's 2.7.10, a homebrew-installed python 2 that's 2.7.15, and a 3.6.3 installation installed from the .pkg on the official python site.

However, in every case, usually they are all installed with explicit versioning as well, so you should be able to do e.g.

```
pip2 install configparser
pip3 install configparser
```

or even

```
pip2.7 install configparser
pip3.6 install configparser
pip3.7 install configparser
```

etc. to point directly at a specific version.

You also can (per one of the other answers) call it as a module from any python version e.g.

```
/my/path/to/a/custom/python -m pip install configparser
```

and that will guarantee to put it in whatever path that python requires - on my system, I have two python 2.7 versions installed; pip2.7 points to the one in /usr/local/bin/python2.7, which is a 2.7.15 install. There is no pip2.7.10 - it only goes to the first subversion - but I can manually do

```
/usr/local/bin/python -m pip list
/usr/bin/python -m pip list
```

and get two different lists of installed modules, as each one has its own site-packages area. So that is always an option.

Answer (score 0):

in python 3, use

`python3 -m pip install configparser`

assuming that python3 is keyword to call python 3.7

in python2, use

`python -m pip install configparser`

assume python is keyword to call python2